# Need help in knowing how to use aws-sdk-node in my current project

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-xray

I have below questions specific to my project.
    - Can we use AWS-SDK with out node.js files / functions on AWS with minimal changes. 
    - Right now the documentation is at very high level. I do not understand where the code changes have to be done.
    - Do I have to make changes in each and every function in *.js files OR one code change per *.js file OR one code change across all *.js files.

I having trouble using AWS-SDK in my node js file. 
I am seeing below error on the console

```js
/TestProject-Lambda/node_modules/hapi/lib/protect.js:80:17)',
  'at Server.<anonymous> (/TestProject/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:259:30)',
  'at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)',
  'at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)',
  'at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:634:12)' ]
Serverless: Replying error in handler


I added below code in one of the *.js file which is entry point for my application

    var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
    AWSXRay.middleware.setSamplingRules('xray-rule.json');
    var logger = require('winston');
    AWSXRay.setLogger(logger);

Below is xray-rule.json

    {
      "version": 1,
      "rules": [
        {
          "description": "Industry Network Record API calls",
          "host": "*",
          "http_method": "*",
          "url_path": "/*",
          "fixed_target": 0,
          "rate": 0.05
        }
      ],
      "default": {
        "fixed_target": 1,
        "rate": 0.1
      }
    }

    "rate": 0.1
  }
}
```

Comment: I having trouble using AWS-SDK in my node js file. 
I am seeing below error on the console

/TestProject-Lambda/node_modules/hapi/lib/protect.js:80:17)',
  'at Server.<anonymous> (/TestProject/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:259:30)',
  'at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)',
  'at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)',
  'at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:634:12)' ]
Serverless: Replying error in handler